# querySelector работает только с одним id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Код работает только с одним id, а нужно чтобы выполнялся на всех найденных.

```js
         var parent = document.getElementById('container');
         setTimeout(function() {
         var div = parent.querySelector('div');
         parent.appendChild(div); //автоматически удалится из старого места
                          }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <div class="news__post " id="container">
         <div>1</div>
         <div>2</div>
     </div>

     <div class="news__post " id="container">
         <div>1</div>
         <div>2</div>
     </div>
```

Код изменяет положение дивов только в первом контейнере, нужно чтобы работал в всех

Comment: querySelectorAll

Comment: @tcpack4 Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node' выдает так ошибку

Comment: непонятно что ты хочешь сделать: перенести все дивы в конец родителя?

Comment: нужно что бы 2 дива менялись местами,так работает но только с одним дивом @Grundy

Comment: _нужно что бы 2 дива менялись местами_ - все равно непонятно. Сейчас у тебя просто один див переставляется в конец родителя. Куда ты хочешь переставить второй див?

Comment: есть один див ,в нем еще 2 дива,нужно что бы они поменялись местами@Grundy

Comment: если _всего_ два дива внутри `parent` то код уже делает то, что ты хочешь

Comment: да,но он работает только с одним id container,а таких блоков 7+ с таким id,надо что бы код сработал на всех Id c таким селектором @Grundy

Comment: `id` должен быть уникальным на странице, именно поэтому странно ожидать, что будет найдено несколько элементов с одним id

Comment: Учите матчасть. JS доходит до первого ID и дальше даже не ищет, ведь по правилам даже HTML - id уникален и не повторяется.

Answer (score 1):

```js
setInterval(function() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.news__post div:first-child');
  
  for (var q=0; q<divs.length; ++q) {
    divs[q].parentElement.appendChild(divs[q])
  }
}, 1000);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: .5em;
}

.news__post {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="news__post">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="news__post">
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
<div class="news__post">
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
<div class="news__post">
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
<div class="news__post">
  <div>9</div>
  <div>0</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = parent.querySelectorAll('div');

for (var q=0; q<divs.length; ++q) {
  var div = divs[q];
}
```

Comment: не удагал :-) там несколько элементов с одним id и проблема в `getElementById`

Comment: @Grundy, ну ладно, написал в другом ответе. Мож даже с id сработает.

Answer (score 0):

как то так

```js
     
     var parent = document.querySelectorAll('[id][id="container"]');
     setTimeout(function() {
         for (var i = 0; i < parent.length; i++) {
            var div = parent[i].querySelector('div');
            parent[i].appendChild(div);
         }
     }, 1000);
```

```html
     <div class="news__post " id="container">
         <div>1</div>
         <div>2</div>
     </div>

     <div class="news__post " id="container">
         <div>1</div>
         <div>2</div>
     </div>
```

P.S. На странице должен быть только один **id**. Лучше будет если ты их сделаешь с **class**